# Android Studio Import doesn't seem to be working

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCZSM.jpg]

I am new to Java and am trying to learn. I am currently stuck and not sure why i am unable to import from a folder.

Comment: Can you also show us DOMParser class?

Answer (score 1):

Your `DOMParser` and `RSSFeed` classes are red underlined, which means they have error(s) in them. Importing will not work properly until you fix those issues in them.

Answer (score 0):

add the dependecies to your gradle file to compile the project DomParser

Comment: I am following this guide. http://www.cogninotech.com/2014/06/creating-android-rss-application-in.html i says for me to add this into mainactivity.class but i only appear to have a mainactivity.java is this not the same?

Comment: It looks like that author put a '.' where he should have ' '. You can't edit .class files - they are produced by the compiler from your .java source code. He probably meant "MainActivity class" (note: space between words, not a file extension) meaning the place where in your code you define `class MainActivity { ... }`.